# DBFlow Select Column

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, orm

I have a table consists of different columns.
I'm getting this error when selecting the specific column.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.juandirection.ModelPoi.POIType' on a null object reference
```

My code for getting the specific column value is this.

```
String type = (new Select(ModelPoi$Table.POITYPE).from(ModelPoi.class).where(Condition.column(ModelPoi$Table.POILAT).is(Global.lat)).querySingle()).POIType;
```

And for my Database table.

```
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Column;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.PrimaryKey;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Table;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

/**
 * Created by Galvez on 11/17/2015.
 */
@Table(databaseName = JuanDirectionDB.dbName)
public class ModelPoi extends BaseModel {
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    long getId;

    @Column
    String POI;

    @Column
    String POIAddress;

    @Column
    String POILat;

    @Column
    String POILong;

    @Column
    String POIType;

    @Column
    String POIInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try your code as.

```
Select select = new Select(ModelPoi$Table.POITYPE).from(ModelPoi.class).where(Condition.column(ModelPoi$Table.POILAT).is(Global.lat)).querySingle();

String type = select!=null ? select.POIType : "NO_RESULT";
```